# Behaviour of shuf and split in a multi processes awk

Tags: bash, multithreading, awk, shuffle

I need to lookup from a long list ("list_of_unique_ID") of shuffled ID ("shuffled_ID") in a huge file ("huge_file") those ID and extract them.
list_of_unique_IDhas been created from "huge_file" but only with its unique ID
The mono process scenario with AWK works fine.

I tried to multiprocess it with the following code : (bash, pseudocode because I can't extract the code from the machine it's running)

```
for sample in $list_of_samples; do
   shuf -n lines_to_be_extracted list_of_unique_ID > shuffled_ID.txt
   if (not_splitted = TRUE)
   then 
      split --number=l/number_of_processes --numeric-suffixes huge_file huge_file_splitted_
      not_splitted = FALSE
   fi
done
for n in number_of_processes ; do
   awk -v =shuffled_ID.txt [AWK function to lookup for the shuffled id] huge_file_splitted_${n} > output_${n} &
done
```

I'm running 5 processes for 3 parameters in parallel.
Which is fairly "simple". I'm just surprised as this script takes much time to run, that given the fact it's shuffled, I have first the output_00 and then output_02 and then output_05 each and every time which are filling first, in this order, before the other ones. I ran it multiple times and tried to swap the splitted huge_file  but it seems that the order is given by what's outputed from the split function.

- I don't think it's logical unless shuffle actually "jumps" over lines but keeps having the same order as the original file ? (But from what I have read, it seems not)
- I might be wrong but I don't really the point of multiprocessing it if the processes are not parallel but subsequent ?

Is there something wrong in my code? Is there something I don't understand clearly?

Thanks !

Edit : thanks for the correction. I corrected my vocabulary :)

Comment: You shuffle list_of_unique_ID (not huge_file) and for your awk task you don't  know which file as given id lands in so you have search all of them anyways so 3x the work with no benefit, right?  If need be, partition the huge file by id, so each process knows if there is a point to searching.  You can also create an index (id to split file) or possible a bloom filter.

Comment: I am trying to analyse randomly picked subsets of the huge file. In list_of_unique_ID, each ID is unique, it however links to up to 150 lines per ID in huge file. So if I shuffle or randomise huge_file I will have only a smaller part of what I am interested in :) My idea was to search on each process for a different "part" of huge_file, not wait for a process to go through it line by line but speeding the search by the number of processes
I'm not sure I'm clear enough? Please, tell me if I'm not

Comment: And the other thing, you split that huge file in a loop.  Do you need to do that?

Comment: No you're absolutely right, it's just because that is a part of a greater code, which does that for several samples (which are looped over). Then the splitting is made for each sample, and removed before going to the next sample as we have limited space. But there's probably many better ways I'm not an expert :)

Comment: the code is a bit confusing (to me) ... would prefer a description of the overall requirement sans any code snippets; what I'm coming up with: **a)** you have a unique list of IDs (how many?), **b)** you have a large file of data (how big? how many lines? how many MBytes?), **c)** for each ID you need to find all matching rows in the huge file (sample IDs? format of big file? sample of big file?), **d)**  you're looking for an efficient/fast method to find the desired data (is the big file sorted by ID?) ... is any of this correct? wrong?

Comment: you mention 'greater code' and 'several examples' so it would help to have more details, eg, how many IDs will you need to analyse? at some point will you need to analyse all of the IDs in 'big file'? is 'big file' sorted by ID? do you have enough room for a 2nd copy of 'big file'? the 'fastest' method is going to be one that has to scan 'big file' the least number of times while making sure to not to fill up a filesystem and not hit an 'out of memory' error; for a smallish number of IDs I'd probably have an `awk` script scan 'big file' once ...

Comment: for a large volume of IDs I might want to consider breaking 'big file' into individual files for each ID so that the 'analyse' step just consists of reading the correct ID file; depending on what 'analyse' means and how often you have to do this, it might make sense to load the data into a database, index the data, and run queries against said (indexed) data ... *shrug* ... a good/fast/efficient design is going to depend on knowing a lot more about the overall process, your requirements, and any (hardware) limitations ...

Comment: Thanks @markp-fuso I'll try to make it clear : 
I am taking one of the 3 parameters I'm trying to look at, it's the one producing the smallest number of ID.
a)Number of ID in list_of_ID : 8,800,000 (530Mb)
Number of ID in shuffled_ID : 444,000 (27Mb)
c)Number of ID in huge_file : 75,000,000 (5,5Gb if not compressed)
Huge file is not sorted, but it could, the order have to my analysis no meaning.
I have enought room for a copy of huge_file, yes
I need to have from  huge_file the full line, not only the ID ($0 in awk)
d) yes I'd like to not spend more than 3-4 days for these 3 parameters

Comment: to complete my precedent comment, I actually know that for parameters having less lines, the job is done in a question of hours/max 48h. The number of line double on each parameter. I have then good chances to get to cut the time under 3 days if I manage to multiprocess it (if a lookup with 5 processes roughly is 5 times faster)
I was actually on the first place, surprised by the "non random" way of picking up the matches

Comment: what are the 2nd and 3rd parameters? are these just more IDs? do you eventually need to analyse **all** IDs?  5.5 GB / 75 million => ~75 characters per line; am I correct in assuming that the end result is a separate output file for each ID? or a separate output file for a group of IDs?  again, just musing ... sounds like the first step would be to get the file sorted by ID (eg, `sort`) and then write a single `awk` script to parse the '(sorted) big file' into separate output files ... new problem ... how many output files (doubtful you want to manage 75 million files)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229459/discussion-between-h-vilbert-and-markp-fuso).

Comment: the whole 'sort and break into smaller files' is .... effectively ... the same thing you'd be doing by loading into a database and creating some indexes (to make data lookup 'faster')

Comment: [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you. Also make sure that all of your requirements are stated in your question, not spread out across comments. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: condensed from the separate chat session: I'd probably focus on getting the 'big file' sorted by ID, make sure the (smaller) list of IDs is also sorted, and then ...
 perhaps look at the `join` command (works best when inputs are sorted) to 'find and match' the smaller set of IDs with the associated IDs/records from the 'big file'

Comment: Also, for performance issues, make sure you benchmark your code so you know what is slow.  Writing huge files over and over might be i/o for instance and not cpu limitation, and for that multiple threads doesn't help.  You want to reduce i/o and failing that faster storage.

Comment: @AllanWind good point; thrashing the disk subsystem (eg, lots of processes reading/writing on the same 'disk') is a huge performance hog (especially if running against older disk technology - spinning disk, SATA); even on newer disk technology (eg, nvme) a high volumes of disk IOs (eg, millions of IO requests, 10's of GBs of data accesses) can cause drives to overheat (if not being actively cooled) which in turn causes the drives to shutdown (until they cool down) which in turn slows down the overall process

Comment: Thanks all for the input. I'll try to implement the different proposal and update here accordingly !